# Need help with proving that $E[x_n, x_m] = \mu\mu^T +I_{nm}Σ$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, gaussian

Need to use the following properties:

E(x) = ${\mu}$

E(${x}{x} ^ {T})=μ {μ } ^ {T} + Σ$

To prove that :

$E[x_n, x_m] = \mu\mu^T +I_{nm}Σ$

$x_n,x_m$ - are vectors

${\mu}$ - mean

Σ - covariance matrix

$I_{nm}$ is identity matrix with vectors $x_n,x_m$ as column vectors

Not quite sure where to start here.

Comment: Hint: inside the expectation substitute $x= x - \mu + \mu$, and note $x^\top = x^\top - \mu^\top + \mu^\top$. Now multiply the vectors out and use linearity.

Comment: sorry not following , can you please elaborate?

Comment: Maybe I'm confused actually: what does $E[x_n,x_m]$ mean? I thought you needed help establishing the first identity.

Comment: My understading from the describtion, althogh do not have a full understadning is that  E[$x_n,x_m$] is an expectation of a data point from Gaussian distribution

Comment: Hmm... yeah we will probably need more to go off of, like exactly how $E[x_n,x_m]$ is defined, in order to make any progress on it.

Answer (score 0):

$E(xx^\top) = E([x-\mu + \mu][x^\top - \mu^\top + \mu^\top])$. Now multiply out everything that is inside the expectation, treating $x-\mu$ and $x^\top - \mu^\top$ as individual terms. Use linearity of the expectation and the definition of the covariance matrix.

Comment: Sorry how does this prove $E[x_n,x_m]=μμ^T+I_{n,m}Σ$